Repeated measures study design with patient drop out for blood concentrations
I am investigating the longitudinal response (course of blood concentration) to a drug in 100 patients. This is a retrospective study. For this purpose, I have blood concentrations over several minutes after taking the medication. Unfortunately, there are not measured values from all patients at all times, as the longitudinal response is only a partial investigation. I therefore created two figures for the evaluation:

course of all existing concentrations over 5 time points; here I used a Mann-Whitney U test for comparison
course of the concentrations where there is an analysis at all measurement times; here I used a Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Unfortunately, the number of cases here is quite low because there are only measured values for 20 patients at all time points.

In the review, I received feedback that I should use a repeated measures study design with patient drop out for the analysis. And here I have the problem that I am unsure which is the appropriate statistical method for this question. I do my analyses with R.
I would be very grateful for any ideas and advice! Many thanks in advance!
